# RelativePanel alignment in Universal App windows 10

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to understand how a RelativePanel works in Universal App for Windows 10 and how splitting of elements can be done.

I'm trying to split the content of the RelativePanel as follows:

```
MainRelativePanel
-------------------------------------------------------
|Image|   RelativePanel1   |      RelativePanel2      |
|Image|   RelativePanel1   |      RelativePanel2      |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

My image control is fixed width i.e. 40 and my RelativePanel properties are set as follows:

```
RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" 
RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
```

This parts works fine.

For my RelativePanel1, I've got the following RelativePanel properties:

```
RelativePanel.RightOf="Image"
```

For my RelativePanel2, I've got the following RelativePanel properties:

```
RelativePanel.RightOf="RelativePanel1"
RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
```

I was hoping that it would split the RelativePanel1 & RelativePanel2 50/50 but instead my RelativePanel1 is taking most of the screen horizontally and my RelativePanel2 is stretching vertically making my DataTemplate in my Listview ridiculously large.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
|Image|   RelativePanel1                          |RP2|
|                                                 |   |
|                                                 |   |
|                                                 |   |
|                                                 |   |
|                                                 |   |
|                                                 |   |
|                                                 |   |
|                                                 |   |
-------------------------------------------------------
|Image|   RelativePanel1                          |RP2|
|                                                 |   |
|                                                 |   |
|                                                 |   |
|                                                 |   |
|                                                 |   |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

I can get it to more or less work if I set a Width on the RelativePanel1 but ideally I would have liked it to be automatic as you would get it when you use a `Grid` control.

Is there a way to achieve this? The reason I'm not using a grid and splitting the columns is that I want the RelativePanel2 to be displayed below the RelativePanel1 in smaller device such as Mobile, and I want them to be displayed next to each other on larger devices such as tablets.

**UPDATED**

Here is the full code as requested for the listview the DataTemplate:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"  
              Background="Red">
        <ListViewItemPresenter ContentMargin="0">
        </ListViewItemPresenter>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2">
                    <RelativePanel Background="#494949">
                        <Image Name="Logo"
                                   Source="{Binding RPMain.Logo}" 
                                   RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" 
                                   RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                                   Width="40"
                                   Height="40"
                                   Margin="5" />

                        <RelativePanel Name="RP1"
                                           Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                           Background="Green"
                                           RelativePanel.RightOf="Logo">

                            <Border Name="RP1Time"
                                        Background="Orange" 
                                        Margin="5,5,0,0">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RP1.Time}" 
                                               Foreground="white"
                                               FontWeight="Bold" />
                            </Border>

                            <TextBlock Name="RP1Title" 
                                           Text="{Binding RP1.Title}" 
                                           Foreground="Black"
                                           FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                           RelativePanel.RightOf="RP1Time" 
                                           Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

                            <TextBlock Name="Description" 
                                           Text="{Binding RP1.Description}" 
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                           RelativePanel.Below="RP1Title"
                                           Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                        </RelativePanel>

                        <RelativePanel Name="RP2"
                                       RelativePanel.RightOf="RP1"
                                       RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                                       Background="Pink"
                                       Margin="0,0,0,0">

                            <Border Name="RP2Time"
                                        Background="Orange" Margin="5,5,0,0">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Now.Time}" 
                                               Foreground="white"
                                               FontWeight="Bold" />
                            </Border>

                            <TextBlock Name="RP2Title"
                                           Text="{Binding RP2.Title}" 
                                           Foreground="Black"
                                           FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                           RelativePanel.RightOf="RP2Time" 
                                           Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

                            <TextBlock Name="RP2Description" 
                                           Text="{Binding RP2.Description}" 
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                           RelativePanel.Below="RP2Title"
                                           Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
                        </RelativePanel>

                    </RelativePanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

I've add background colours to RP1 & RP2 RelativePanels so you can clearly see that it doesn't get split evenly and this is what I'd like to achieve but as mentioned, I can't use a Grid, as I'd like to display RP2 below RP1 on smaller devices.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using RP1 and RP2 and not another control like Grid/StackPanel? Could you post the complete DataTemplate, I think we're missing important pieces like e.g. Width/Height properties to help you out.

Comment: @Bart I've updated my answer as requested. Hopefully this will help. One thing to remember is that I don't want to use fixed width between RP1 & RP2. I'd like them to split evenly on larger devices and RP2 to display full width below RP1 on smaller devices. Note that I've got to the Adaptive UI resizing part just yet as I'm first trying to get it to split evenly..

Comment: What @Bart is suggesting makes sense! Currently there is no way to change widths of RP like grid column system ( auto or * ) or you need to calculate it yourself. So best is to still use grid columns and control the content and size of them in the adaptive triggers. You can always extract content and place it underneath other stuff if needed.

Comment: @Depechie. I ended up going down this route. Required a lot of re-jigging but got what I wanted at the end. I ended up putting a grid with 3 columns, and put each of my RelativePanels in each column. My grid has also 2 rows and the second row is empty and therefore is not displayed and when the size is detected for a small device, it puts the third RelativePanel (RP2) in row 1, changes ColumnSpan for both RP1 & RP2 to stretch all the way across the screen. The first Column was also changed to have it RowSpan set to 2. Then it was just a case of changing various individual properties.